# can't render libGDX renderable with texture

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I was trying to render a mesh (that i created programmatically) with textures. Everything works fine except that it doesn't render the texture. It's just a black triangle. Here is a simplified version of the code (which doesn't work either):

```
public ModelBatch batch;
public OrthographicCamera cam;
public Renderable renderable;

@Override
public void create () {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(5, 5);
    batch = new ModelBatch();

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3,
            new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2, "a_position"),
            new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoord")
    );

    mesh.setVertices(new float[]{
            0, 0,   0, 0,
            1, 0,   1, 0,
            1, 1,   1, 1
    });
    mesh.setIndices(new short[]{
            0, 1, 2
    });

    renderable = new Renderable();
    renderable.primitiveType = GL20.GL_TRIANGLES;
    renderable.mesh = mesh;
    renderable.meshPartOffset = 0;
    renderable.meshPartSize = mesh.getNumIndices();
    renderable.material = new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(new Texture("badlogic.jpg")));
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin(cam);
    batch.render(renderable);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots or how it should be rendered ?

Comment: How it looks like:
[link](http://nixusgs.com/stackoverflow/screen_0.png)

How it should look like:
[link](http://nixusgs.com/stackoverflow/screen_1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I should have created the mesh this way:

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3,
        new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, 2, "a_position"),
        new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoord0")
);
```

The difference is that now the alias in the texture coordinates attribute is a_texCoord0 instead of a_texCoord.